# how can i count distinct values associative array in php

Tags: php, facebook

i have F8 like json file and i want to store and count the categories in an array i.e for simple array in php

```
function array_icount_values($array) {
   $rtarray = array();
    foreach($array as $value) $rtarray[strtolower($value)]++;
    return $rtarray; 
$ar = array('red', 'green', 'blue', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'blue', 'green');
//$ar = array_icount_values($re);
```

its output will be

```
[red]=>4
[blue]=>3
[green]=>2
```

i want same result for this file

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "name": "The Lord of the Rings Trilogy (Official Page)",
         "category": "Movie"         
      },
      {
         "name": "Snatch",
         "category": "Movie"

      },
      {         "name": "The Social Network Movie",
         "category": "Movie"         
      },
      {         "name": "Scarface",
         "category": "public figure"         
      },
      {         "name": "Johnny Depp",
         "category": "Actor/director"         
      },
      {
         "name": "Once Upon a Time in the West",
         "category": "public figure"         
      },
      {         "name": "Legend of the Guardians: The Owls of Ga'Hoole",
         "category": "public figure"         
      },
      {         "name": "Once Upon a Time in America",
         "category": "public figure"       
      },
      {         "name": "Butch Cassidy and the Sundance Kid",
         "category": "public figure"
        },
      {         "name": "Fracture",
         "category": "public figure"
              },
      {         "name": "Invictus",
         "category": "public figure"

      },
      { "name": "Pride and Glory",
         "category": "public figure"
      }
   ]
}
```

**Note** that i just want the categories count i.e

```
[Movies]=>5 [Tv show]=>4 etc
```

i used this code

```
function array_icount_values($array) {
    $ret_ar=array();
    foreach($array['data'] as $key=>$val)
    {
        print_r(array_count_values($val));
     }}
$string = file_get_contents("likes.json");
$json_a=json_decode($string,true);
$re=array_icount_values($json_a);
```

But this give strange result.

Comment: decode json + `foreach($array as $value) $rtarray[strtolower($value['category'])]++;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text you have there is a JSON. Just decode it an use the same method to count categories as in the function you previously provided. Check this out: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Hope I could help, all the best...

LE:

```
$arr=json_decode($str);
foreach($arr['data'] as $value){
    $categCount[$value['category']]++;
}
```

var_dump($categCount);// should give you the categories count

Comment: i decode the json file and apply the method but not get my result

Comment: Apply the method (as ideea),not the function :). After you decode it you should get an array like $array['data'], I'll give you the rest above in a sec

Comment: Using $value['category'] as index gives an "undefined index" exception, whats the right approach to solve this? :)

Comment: for the love of God Dane411 :)), replace

$categCount[$value['category']]++;

with

(!empty($categCount[$value['category']])?$categCount[$value['category']]++:$categCount[$value['category']]=1);